# ROS2 separate directory for Python nodes

Tags: python, package, nodes, ros2

Is it possible to have a separate directory for Python nodes in ROS2 (foxy)?

```
python_pkg/
│
├─ python_pkg/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ my_module.py
│  └─ hello_world.py
|
├─ nodes/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  └─ simple_node.py
|
└─ ...
```

In `setup.py` I have tried adding:

```py
setup(
    name="python_pkg",
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
                'hello_world = python_pkg.hello_world:main',
                'simple_node = nodes.simple_node:main',
        ],
},
)
```

If I source the workspace and run `ros2 run python_pkg simple_node` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nodes'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem today and came across your question. The way to do it is by adding your node in your data_files first, so in setup.py:

```
data_files=[
    ...,
    ('lib/' + package_name, ['./nodes' + '/simple_node.py'])
],
```

Then add the node to your entry_points:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        "simple_node = simple_node:main",
    ],
},
```

Comment: Sweet, it works! I changed it to the following to add all `.py` nodes: `data_files=[(f'lib/{package_name}', glob('nodes/*.py')), ...]`.